# Is Objective C the preferred way to write OSX applications?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I've been assigned a new task at my company to rewrite one of applications to Mac OSX. I just started learning about OSX programming and it looks like the native language of Mac OSX is Objective C.

Therefor I've a question - is Objective C the preferred way to write OSX applications? And also does anyone know if there are alternatives to Objective C? (I'm already familiar with C and C++.)

Comment: Yes, Objective-C is preferred. And if you know C, then it's easy to deduce that anything you can do in Objective-C you can do in C as well.

Comment: Objective-c is the preferred language by Apple. It is an extension to C and if you know C, you will catch on very fast. It is very common to write applications in a mixture of C and Objective-C. You have the option to write in C++ too.